# how to find two integers that multiply 20

Tags: c++

I have an array of elements, and I want to find two elements that multiply to 20. I need help using C++.

```cpp
int arr[]={2,4,1,6,5,40,-1};
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    if(arr[i]*arr[i+1]==20)
        cout<<arr[i+1]<<"and"<<arr[i];
}
```

Comment: In addition to going out of bounds, you're only comparing adjacent elements. 4 and 5 are not adjacent, so you'll miss them.

Comment: Is the value `-1` at the end of the array a special value to mark the end of the array? Or is it just a value without any special meaning?

Comment: Look for factors of `20`  (`1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, `10`, `20` or their negatives).  For each factor found that has magnitude `4` (technically the square root of 20, rounded down) or less, check if `20/f` is present.    If both `f` and `20/f` are present, they are a pair that multiply to `20`.

Comment: Is your goal to find two numbers using only one pass through the array?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is going out of bounds of the array.  When `i` reaches the index of the `-1` element, accessing `arr[i+1]` is *undefined behavior*.

Also, your loop is comparing only *adjacent* elements, but the 2 numbers in your example that actually multiply to `20` are not adjacent to each other in the array.

You need a second loop to compare non-adjacent elements, eg:

```cpp
int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 40, -1};
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 6; j++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] * arr[j]) == 20)
            std::cout << arr[i] << " and " << arr[j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 4 and 5

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Zuzquh)

If you want to compare only adjacent elements, you will have to sort the 
array first, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 40, -1};
std::sort(arr, arr + 7);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if ((arr[i] * arr[i + 1]) == 20)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " and " << arr[i + 1] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> 4 and 5

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/NpxpOf)

Comment: Truly grateful thanks you @Remy Lebeau